# Java get resource is not working

Tags: java

I try to read a resource file from my application but it doesn't work.

Code:

```
String filename = getClass().getClassLoader().getResource("test.xsd").getFile();
System.out.println(filename);
File file = new File(filename);
System.out.println(file.exists());
```

Output when I execute the jar-file:

> file:/C:/Users/username/Repo/run/Application.jar!/test.xsd
>   false

It works when I run the application from IntelliJ but not when I execute the jar-file. If I open my jar-file with 7-zip test.xsd is located in the root-folder. Why isn't the code working when I execute the jar-file?

Comment: Try move the "test.xsd" into the classes folder. As you can see, your calling getClassLoader() which search for files in the classpath.

Comment: Can you inspect the contents of the jar, Is your file getting packaged into the jar

Comment: IntelliJ may have added your root folder as classpath

Comment: @AnupamSaini As I wrote in the question test.xsd is in the root-folder of the jar-file.

Comment: If you use Maven to build the jar, try moving or create the directory structure like ..src/main/resources then move any resources there and Maven will package them in the classpath vailable for you to use with .getResource(...).

Answer (score 1):

Also, `File` refers to actual OS file-system files; in the OS's file-system, there is only a jar file, and that jar file is not a folder. You should either extract the contents of the URL to a temporary file, or operate with its bytes in-memory or as a stream.

Note that `myURL.getFile()` is returning a String representation, and not an actual `File`. In a similar way, this will **not** work:

```
 File f = new URL("http://www.example.com/docs/resource1.html").getFile();
 f.exists(); // always false - will not be found in the local filesystem
```

A nice wrapper could be the following:

```
public static File openResourceAsTempFile(ClassLoader loader, String resourceName) 
       throws IOException {
    Path tmpPath = Files.createTempFile(null, null);
    try (InputStream is = loader.getResourceAsStream(resourceName)) {
        Files.copy(is, tmpPath, StandardCopyOption.REPLACE_EXISTING);
        return tmpPath.toFile();
    } catch (Exception e) {
        if (Files.exists(tmpPath)) Files.delete(tmpPath);
        throw new IOException("Could not create temp file '" + tmpPath
                + "' for resource '" + resourceName + "': " + e, e);
    }
}
```

Comment: URL url = getClass().getClassLoader().getResource("/test.xsd"); gives url null.

Comment: Hmm, you are right. In my last project it was necessary, but I cannot reproduce this behavior. I edited out that part, and added sample code to copy the resource to a temporary file that should fix your problem. Remember to remove the temporary file after you are done with it!